# How do I create a Row with a defined schema in Spark-Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'd like to create a Row with a schema from a case class to test one of my map functions. The most straightforward way I can think of doing this is:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

case class MyCaseClass(foo: String, bar: Option[String])

def buildRowWithSchema(record: MyCaseClass): Row = {
    sparkSession.createDataFrame(Seq(record)).collect.head
}
```

However, this seemed like a lot of overhead to just get a single Row, so I looked into how I could directly create a Row with a schema. This led me to:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoders, Row}

def buildRowWithSchemaV2(record: MyCaseClass): Row = {
    val recordValues: Array[Any] = record.getClass.getDeclaredFields.map((field) => {
        field.setAccessible(true)
        field.get(record)
    })
    new GenericRowWithSchema(recordValues, Encoders.product[MyCaseClass].schema)
}
```

Unfortunately, the Row that the second version returns is different from the first Row. Option fields in the first version are reduced to their primitive values, while they are still Options in the second version. Also, the second version is quite unwieldy.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The second version is returning `Option` itself for the `bar` case class field, thus you are not getting primitive value as the first version. you can use the following code for primitive values

```
def buildRowWithSchemaV2(record: MyCaseClass): Row = {
  val recordValues: Array[Any] = record.getClass.getDeclaredFields.map((field) => {
    field.setAccessible(true)
    val returnValue = field.get(record)
    if(returnValue.isInstanceOf[Option[String]]){
      returnValue.asInstanceOf[Option[String]].get
    }
    else
      returnValue
  })
  new GenericRowWithSchema(recordValues, Encoders.product[MyCaseClass].schema)
}
```

But meanwhile I would suggest you to use `DataFrame` or `DataSet`.

`DataFrame` and `DataSet` are themselves collections of `Row with schema`.
So when you have a `case class` defined, you just need to `encode` your input data into `case class`
For example:
lets say you have input data as

```
val data = Seq(("test1", "value1"),("test2", "value2"),("test3", "value3"),("test4", null))
```

If you have a text file you can read it with `sparkContext.textFile` and `split` according to your need. 
Now when you have converted your data to `RDD`, converting it to `dataframe` or `dataset` is two lines code

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
val dataFrame = data.map(d => MyCaseClass(d._1, Option(d._2))).toDF
```

`.toDS` would generate `dataset`
Thus you have collection of `Rows with schema`

for validation you can do the followings

```
println(dataFrame.schema)    //for checking if there is schema

println(dataFrame.take(1).getClass.getName) //for checking if it is a collection of Rows
```

Hope you have the right answer.

Comment: `take(1)` is not much different albeit more efficient than `collect.head`. I believe the OP wants to entirely skip the creation of an RDD.

Comment: @HristoIliev, I did `take(1)` just to validate/show that `dataframe` or `dataset` is collection of `Row` with `schema`.

Comment: But the OP wants a single `Row`, not a `DataSet` or a `DataFrame`. Now, I'm not really sure why, because he can easily test a map function on a distributed collection with a single element.

Comment: @HristoIliev, yes I agree that OP wants a single `Row` to be generated for each operation. But that would **create many tasks and much memory usage** when working with `big data`. So as `dataFrame` or `dataSet` is in itself a collection of `Row with schema`, I would recommend these to be used. Don't you agree?

Comment: He is trying to test something, not create big data row by row.